# How To Compile, Build and Debug MASM Using Visual Studios 2005 Standard

Tags: assembly, windows-xp, x86, masm

I am trying to compile, build and debug 16-bit assembly programs using Visual Studio 2005 Standard but can't figure out how to do this. I am running MASM 6.14.8444 version and I have found some helpful links which do not seem to work at least not for me (see below). I do not have access to Visual Studio 2008/2010 Express Edition. I am trying to compile complete Assembly programs in VS2005 Standard not using inline assembly.

Here are some links I found that I have tried but get compiling errors which I cannot sort out.

http://kipirvine.com/asm/4th/ide/vsnet/index.htm#16-bit
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4548763/compiling-assembly-in-windows
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vcgeneral/thread/3e24f203-c516-41e2-a7bf-325452157336

Thanks in advance

Victor

Comment: You have to use some kind of target dependent tools. What are you targeting? 16-bit assembly went out of fashion with Windows 3, and later tools will not target that.

Comment: Thanks Bo. I am only planning to run this program on Windows XP. I am able to run these DOS 16 bit programs on Windows XP without any trouble but I would like to have the use of a debugger hence my reason to integrate VS6.0 or VS2005.

Comment: I believe support for that disappeared around VC 1.5 :-) If you have found some old programs, perhaps someone has already ported them to 32-bit? Or 64-bit...

Comment: @Bo thanks. Actually the code is 16-bit code and they are very simple/basic code for newcomers to assembly. I don't know how to tell if they have been ported to 32/64 bit. They only make reference to 8,16 bit registers only. I have add success in writing my own 16 bit basic programs that work using WinASM and MASM32 on Windows XP. Everything runs inside a console window.

Comment: Check out something here: http://thestarman.pcministry.com/asm/masm.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just download the [MASM32 SDK](http://masm32.com/) it contains everything you need to Assemble and Link 16 and 32 bit programs.  Plus it has sample programs with source, tons of macros with source, a great libray with source etc...

Comment: Gunner thank you for the reply. I agree with you and that is the version that I have downloaded and installed but what I really need is the ability to debug and view contents of registers.

Comment: Then you need a debugger!  OllyDbg is a great one.

Comment: Thanks again to everyone for all their contributions. I've decided to give another debugger a try like the one suggested by Gunner.

Comment: Well, haven't used 16bit code in ages, Olly is a 32bit debugger.  There are a few out there you can search for.

Answer (score 1):

The last Visual C++ to support 16 bit was Visual C++ 1.52. It was also included in Visual C++ 2.0, but all subsequent versions were 32-bit only.

However, that's not the only possibility. MASM32 has been mentioned, but I would also recommend Borland's TASM. If not for assembling (its syntax is somewhat different from MASM) then at least for debugging - Turbo Debugger was one of the best DOS debuggers.

Comment: thanks. Would it be not possible that the 32-bit compiler and linker not able to compile the above code ? That is 16 bit code not a subset of 32 bit assembly ? I also was able to download and install VS2005 Exress and now get the following errors:                                                             > Assembling: ..\..\Source1.asm
1>..\..\Source1.asm(20) : error A2006: undefined symbol : DGROUP
1>..\..\Source1.asm(87) : warning A4023: with /coff switch, leading underscore required for start address : START
1>Project : error PRJ0019: A tool returned an error code from "Assembling..."

Comment: thanks. Your absolutely right about the last known version of VS that supported DOS 16-bit programs. I actually at the moment have installed Visual C++ 2005 Express which comes with MASM compiler and linker. Getting some errors on building these basic 16-bit programs.