# Can I compile .asm files in Microsoft Visiual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, assembly

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Compiling Assembly in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4548763/compiling-assembly-in-visual-studio)

Can I compile ".asm " files/assembly language programs in Microsoft Visiual Studio 2010?
If yes, is it better to use Masm or Microsoft Visual Studio?

Comment: It appears that you are still looking for an assembler, and haven't made up your mind. In that case, I'll recommend [NASM](http://www.nasm.us/). I'd use that over both VS and MASM.

Comment: Yes you can look at this [SO Question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4548763/479512).

Comment: I actually recommend yasm for VS