# Where is the MASM SDK?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, assembly, visual-studio-2013, masm, masm32

The article [Assembly Programming with Visual Studio.NET](http://resources.infosecinstitute.com/assembly-programming-visual-studio-net/) says that Visual Studio includes the MASM SDK but I have been unable to find it, either in VS 2010 or VS 2013. I found the specified files in MASM from MASM32.com. The code in the article works with the files from MASM32.com but I want to know what I missed. Where is the MASM supplied with VS? The article indicates that there is nothing more to download, that MASM is part of VS. Is that correct or not?

Comment: There has never been an "SDK".  It is included with VS, the 32-bit version is stored in vc\bin\ml.exe, the 64-bit version in vc\bin\amd64\ml64.exe.  It is directly usable in a VS project, [check here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4549741/17034).

Comment: Thank you Hans. That is the assembler itself but for the Windows API stuff, we need files (such as windows.inc) defining the API, right? The article refers to files that are unique to asm that I do not find in VS.

Comment: Such files existed in DDK versions a long, long time ago.  Microsoft doesn't develop anything in assembly anymore.

Comment: There is/was a utility called H2INC included with MASM (ML.EXE) 6.11, that converted C (not C++) .h files to .inc files. I don't know if it would work with windows.h, or where to get H2INC these days.

Comment: Thank you. The important thing is that VS does not include all the files that the article says it does.