# How to enable Assembly Language support in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: assembly, visual-studio-2015

I installed Visual Studio 2015 Community and want to use Assembly Languege in 32bit mostly.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Compiling Assembly in Visual Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4548763/compiling-assembly-in-visual-studio)

Comment: That will work in VS2015?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Despite what sanaris said, it *IS* possible to build masm using VS2015.  However this is a trick you have to know.

You will need to right click on the project (not the solution) and select "Build Dependencies/Build Customizations".  From there, check the "masm" box.

That's it.  Now asm files will be built using ml and linked in to your executable as expected.

Note that this is basically the sames as the instructions for VS2010, except that there is one more layer of menu (must look under Build Dependencies).

If you already have asm files added to your project, they probably got added as "Does not participate in build."  You can either remove/re-add them, or right click on the file and change the "Item Type" to "Microsoft Macro Assembler."

Answer (score 3):

No, support for MASM type was dropped from Visual Studio (looking at VS2015 now).

Full build chain exists cl.exe + ml64.exe + link.exe.

But there is not such thing as "MASM file" in VS2015 editor.

Probably it could be added by some "online package", but I would not rely on that and just use two-step process: build ASM outside + build project.

Upgraded projects from previous versions of VS will obtain MASM build targets (unlike manually created) for backward compatibility.

I guess it will be dropped in favour of intrinsics use.

PS. You can download examples from this book http://www.apress.com/9781484200650 to see how VS2015 handles ASM, it just does not have any highlight or asm type.

Best choice is to go outside of VS for that work.